# How to add custom batch action in Directus 7?

Tags: php, batch-processing, directus

I'm wondering about how to create/add custom batch actions to collections in Directus 7? I've already read [about Hooks](https://docs.directus.io/extensions/hooks.html) but couldn't find any solution about how to implement custom actions per collection for batch processing.

My example is a collection of `products` that I want to select and send them per email (custom batch action) to a friend.

Is there a way to implement this easily in API?